# Discord node js "TypeError: channel.send is not a function"

Tags: node.js, discord

Currently creating a discord bot and ran into some errors claiming that "channel.send" is not a function.

This is for a command which allows the bot to message every channel in the guild.

```
case "msgall":
    if (!args[1]) return message.reply("enter a msg")
    if (message.author.bot) return undefined;
    announce = args.slice(1).join(" ")
    message.delete();
    message.guild.channels.forEach(channel=>{
        channel.send(announce)
        channel.send(announce)
        channel.send(announce)
    }).catch(console.log);
    break;
```

It should be able to send a message to every channel on the server, but it keeps throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is due to message.guild.channels not being an array of Channel objects. As per [documentation](https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/frequently-asked-questions.md), you first need to find the channel (by name or channel id):

> `// Get a Channel by Name
>   message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "channel-name");
>   // returns <Channel>`

I suggest you create an array of channel names (or ids) and iterate over that array. For example:

```
const channels = ['channel-1', 'channel-2'];
channels.forEach(c => {
  const ch = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === c);
  ch.send(announce);
});
```